# Ссылка, которая отменяет последнее действие пользователя

Tags: javascript, html, popup

Есть ссылка, она открывает ---> popup 1, в нем есть ссылка, которая открывает ---> popup 2, в котором есть кнопка назад, которая возвращает нас к ---> popup 1. Проблема в том, что ссылка "назад" должна отменять последнее действие (т.е. открытие popup2) и открывать popup1. Но таких подобных модальных окон много, поэтому нужен универсальный скрипт. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: если предыдущий попап не закрываете, то ищите окно родителя для ссылки и его закрывайте. иначе кидайте их в стэк.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз уж не было кода - пробуем как-то вот так:

```js
let popups = document.querySelectorAll('.popup');
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.link');

Array.from(buttons).forEach(function(el){
 el.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(!el.classList.contains('back')) {
   let linkTo = this.getAttribute('data-link'),
   findElement = document.getElementById(linkTo);
   findElement.classList.add('active'); 
  } else {   
   el.parentElement.classList.remove('active')
  }  
 })
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #645E9D;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.popup {
  position: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 60px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 500ms;
  transition: 500ms;
  padding: 20px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
          transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.popup.active:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
          transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.popup.active:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(20%, 20%);
          transform: translate(20%, 20%);
}
.popup.active:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(30%, 30%);
          transform: translate(30%, 30%);
}
.popup.active:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(40%, 40%);
          transform: translate(40%, 40%);
}
.popup.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a class="link" data-link="popup-1">first popup</a>
<div id="popup-1" class="popup">
 <h1>First popup</h1>
 <a data-link='popup-4' class="link">fourth popup</a>
 <a data-link='popup-2' class="link">second popup</a>
 <a class="link back">Back to...</a>
</div>

<div id="popup-2" class="popup">
 <h1>Second popup</h1>
 <a data-link="popup-3" class="link">third popup</a>
 <a data-link="popup-1" class="link back">Back to...</a>
</div>

<div id="popup-3" class="popup">
 <h1>Third popup</h1>
 <a data-link="popup-3" class="link">fourth popup</a>
 <a data-link="popup-2" class="link back">Back to...</a>
</div>
<div id="popup-4" class="popup">
 <h1>Fourth popup</h1>
 <a data-link="popup-3" class="link back">Back to...</a>
</div>
```

Comment: А как можно реализовать этот код в magnific-popup? Могу предоставить мой примерный html и js